# I want to fill html table td's with mathematical operation results using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to fill html table td's with mathematical operation results using javascript. Here's my table:

```
<table class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Trainer</th> 
  <th>Battles</th> 
  <th>Wins</th> 
  <th>Losses</th> 
  <th>Win Rate</th>
  <th>Rating</th>
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
  <td></td>
  <td>CLBGM</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>9</td> 
  <td>13</td> 
  <td></td> 
  <td></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td></td>
  <td>Galakthor</td>
  <td>44</td>
  <td>26</td> 
  <td>18</td> 
  <td></td> 
  <td></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
  <td></td>
  <td>JOOY</td>
  <td>41</td>
  <td>20</td> 
  <td>21</td> 
  <td></td> 
  <td></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
  <td></td>
  <td>Matiaz98</td> 
  <td>30</td>
  <td>18</td> 
  <td>12</td> 
  <td></td> 
  <td></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
  <td></td>
  <td>PokeCraftMariano</td> 
  <td>30</td>
  <td>16</td> 
  <td>14</td> 
  <td></td> 
  <td></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td></td>
  <td>Rockemc</td> 
  <td>40</td>
  <td>23</td> 
  <td>17</td> 
  <td></td> 
  <td></td> 
</tr>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

I want "Win Rate" column to display this result: "[(Wins/Battles)x100]%".
And "Rating" column may display this: "[(Wins)x7]-[(Losses)x3]".

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: JavaScript (this is what i have right now)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5c8cuzcww0bjua4/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2gbxvhkskdsch5p/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("table").tablesorter({
    // prevent first column from being sortable
    headers: {
        0: { sorter: false }
    },
    // apply custom widget
    widgets: ['numbering']
}); 
      });
      $.tablesorter.addWidget({
    id: "numbering",
    format: function(table) {
        var c = table.config;
        $("tr:visible", table.tBodies[0]).each(function(i) {
            $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(i + 1);
        });
    }
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you post your attempted JavaScript code?

Comment: Ok. I added what i have in the script section :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First, welcome to the StackOverflow community.  Please keep in mind that, in order to get more response, you should provide as much as information in the question.*

Now, you need to populate your table from the data before you use sorting plug-in.

Here is the JSON representation of your data.

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify([{
    trainer: "CTBGM",
    win: 9,
    loss: 13
}, {
    trainer: "Galakthor",
    win: 26,
    loss: 18
}, {
    trainer: "JOOY",
    win: 20,
    loss: 21
}, {
    trainer: "Matiaz98",
    win: 18,
    loss: 12
}, {
    trainer: "PokeCraftMariano",
    win: 16,
    loss: 14
}, {
    trainer: "Rockemc",
    win: 23,
    loss: 17
}]);
```

Next; you need a class which will take the information pushed in and calculates the mathematical operations etc.

```
 var ScoreTable = (function () {
    function scoreTable(trainer, win, loss) {
        this.position = '';
        this.trainer = trainer;
        this.win = win;
        this.loss = loss;
        this.battles = this.win + this.loss;
        this.winrate = this.win / this.battles;
        this.rating = this.win * 7 - this.loss * 3;
    }
    return scoreTable;
})();
```

Third; part that creates the ScoreTable instances based on data passed in, constructs the rows from columns and adds into the table

```
function getColumn(value) {
    return $('<td>' + value + '</td>');
}

function addRow(item) {
    var row = $("<tr />");
    $("#dataTable").append(row);

    row.append(getColumn(item.position));
    row.append(getColumn(item.trainer));
    row.append(getColumn(item.battles));
    row.append(getColumn(item.win));
    row.append(getColumn(item.loss));
    row.append(getColumn((item.winrate * 100).toFixed(0) + '%'));
    row.append(getColumn(item.rating));
}

function populate(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var item = new ScoreTable(data[i].trainer, data[i].win, data[i].loss);
        addRow(item);
    }
}
```

And the final part; calling the table constructor with the raw data received.  You will probably retrieve your data via AJAX but for simplicity purposes I will present with parsing method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var parsedData = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
    populate(parsedData);
});
```

You may find the **complete solution** at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cilerler/aZ3nz/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. This is what i got: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rbc7fvxottg5gyu/sample.html I don't know what I've done wrong. 1. I changed '#dataTable' for '.tablesorter', because i want to do more than 1 table. 2. It seems that I need to define <thead> and <tbody> in order to use the tablesorter plugin: http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Getting-Started P.S.: Don't pay attention to the spanish text of my html code ^^, Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Since you are a newbie here, I updated the solution at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cilerler/aZ3nz/) for sorting. But please do not expand the coverage of the question at comments. If you have questions **related to the answer**, sure ask them but mark the answer as accepted first. If you have **new questions**, ask them separately please. e.g.: Your initial question was related to the calculation, not the sorting and you received the answer but didn't mark it as accepted and expanded the questions coverage at comment.  StackOverflow does not work that way ;-)

Comment: Awesome! :) And thanks for the advice. I modified the code a little bit and added another widget in the js code. But the arrows are not showing and when I click on a header, it doesn't change its color to blue (like the documentation page's demo, that's why I attached that style.css) anymore =/

Comment: Great! I see what is the problem in your code **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined** but again, it is totally different question.  Let me know if you create a new question for that. =) also check the following link to learn how to use [Developer Console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index) Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was related to my previous question Dx Here's my new question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125307/tablersorters-blue-style-doesnt-show-arrows-and-color-change-header